pytest does not exit after the test ends
from ... import fastapp
import pytest
from async_asgi_testclient import TestClient as AsyncClient
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

client = TestClient(fastapp)

@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_something():
    async def fetch_stream():
        async with AsyncClient(fastapp) as ac:
            url = f"/api/..."
            response = await ac.post(
                url,
                json={...},
                stream=True,
            )
            result = ""
            async for line in response.iter_content(2):
                line = line.decode("utf-8").strip()
                result += line

            if (
                len(result) > 0
                and "failed" not in result
            ):
                print("success!")
                assert True

            else:
                print("false!")
                assert False

    await fetch_stream()

Above is my code.
I execute FastAPI server using docker.
Test Command is "docker exec container_name pytest /app/tests/ -W ignore -s --capture=no"
After This Command Test Is Success. But Pytest Does Not Exit.
Terminal Log is below.
Domething test print
============================== 1 passed in 36.76s ==============================

Spec
async-asgi-testclient==1.4.11
pytest-asyncio==0.14.0
pytest-timeout==2.3.1
pytest==7.4.3`


I applied @pytest.mark.timeout(60) to test_something.
It limit test code execution time. However, it did not affect the termination of pytest.

docker exec timeout apply. It affet the termination of pytest. But Exit Code is not zero. I use exit code to github action test. Detail command is below


docker exec container_name timeout 60 pytest /app/tests/ -W ignore -s --capture=no  


I applied exit(code=0). Test failed But It Does not affect the termination of pytest

=========================== short test summary info ============================
FAILED tests/api/test_something.py::test_something - SystemExit: 0
FAILED tests/api/test_something2.py::test_something2 - SystemExit: 0
============================== 2 failed in 42.55s ==============================


I applied httpx. But it use real api. So It does not use test db.


It is because of infinity non stop event.
my asgi.py code is below.
@fastapp.on_event("startup")
def startup_event():
    start_memory_monitoring()


The start_memory_monitoring function is non stop memory monitoring function.
After delete this code pytest execution exit normally after test complete.

What you can consider next time for the sake of testing purposes, is creating a fixture that will catch that start_memory_monitoring part of your code as if you wanted to mock it out and within that fixture you can create a yield so that when it returns back after a test you can call an explicit stop on that memory monitoring. This is assuming you want this running with your code anyway.
